# javascript event.target.match or event.target.closest does not work

Tags: javascript

In my project, I have a cart icon that when mouse clicks on the icon needs to unfold a dropdown list with two link options. When the mouse is clicking on somewhere else or in a blank space the dropdown list needs to dissapear.

Here is a snippet of my html template which shows upon clicking on the element with id `shoppingCartIcon` the javascript function `cartIconClicked()` is called.

```
<div class="container-fluid sticky-top" id="takeawayHeaderCartContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-11" id="cartIconContent">
            <i class="fa dropbtn" id="shoppingCartIcon" onclick="cartIconClicked()">&#xf07a;</i> <!--this code codes for the shopping cart icon-->
            <span class='badge badge-warning' id='lblCartCount'> 
                {% if sessionValidity %}
                    {{totalCartItems}}
                {% else %}
                0 
                {% endif %}
            </span>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Option 1</a>
                <a href="#">Option 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

In my css file I have this snippet.

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#takeawayHeaderCartContainer {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#shoppingCartIcon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  float: right;
  color: blue;
}

#lblCartCount {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
}

.badge {
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
.label-warning[href],
.badge-warning[href] {
  background-color: #c67605;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

I am not sure if I fully graps the last line `.show {display:block;}` in above css style because we do not have a show class in the html template to begin with. I therefore guess it is meant for the javascript - see below. I got this script from [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp). Can someone explain to me what this line in particular `classList.toggle("show")` does? I guess it switches the class "show" on and off for the dropdown list? My biggest problem is though, this line `if (!event.target.closest('.fa dropbtn'))`. This line gets fired every time both when I click on the cart icon and somewhere else, which is NOT the intension. It should get fired if the user clicks somewhere else than the cart icon, in which case a check will be performed to see if the drop down list has the "show" on and if so it should be removed, leading to drop down list dissapearing - see the link tutorial for full description.

```
function cartIconClicked() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  
  // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
      console.log(event.target);
      if (!event.target.closest('.fa dropbtn')) 
      {
        console.log("we are here");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo:

```
if (!event.target.closest('.fa dropbtn'))
```

must be

```
if (!event.target.closest('.fa.dropbtn'))
```

[`classList.toggle('show')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) adds the class `show` if it's not present, and removes it if present.